# Curl request script / html form

Tags: html, curl

Say I perform a curl request to get some json back for teams within my api. e.g

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -X GET -G     --data-urlencode "limit=100"    --data-urlencode "offset=0"   "https://my.api.com/teams"
```

Is there anyway I can turn this into a script within some html to be run and display my information back on demand?

I was thinking an input box `Team Name` where the user enters what team they want and the script runs  adding a variable `?team=`

I am new to APIs so if what I am thinking of is totally wrong I apologise in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with PHP, you can use the PHP cURL library to make the same request and then output the response as HTML.  Something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://my.api.com/teams?getKey1=getValue1&getKey2=getValue2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Your_Header_1: value1',
    'Your_Header_2: value2'
));

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $server_output;
?>
</body>
</html>
```